# What will happen if a user reaches the reputation cap after being serial voted?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-limit

As there is a reputation cap of 200 per day, what will happen in the following scenario:

Firstly,

> A user earned 10 reputation after a user upvoted him.

Secondly,

> He was serial upvoted by a different user and thus got another 200 reputation.
>
> But only 190 will be credited as he already has 10 reputation.

Thirdly

> Another user upvoted him thus earning him 10 more reputation.
>
> But it couldn't be credited as he already earned 210 reputation.

In conclusion, he received 220 reputation after being upvoted by 2 different users and serial upvoted by another user. But only 200 is being credited.

- In this story, there's 3 **different** users upvoting

**So, when the serial voting script detects it:**

Will it reverse the 200 reputation from the serial upvoting only, thus leaving him with just earning 10 reputation on that day?

Or will it reverse the 200 reputation from the serial upvoting and credit the subsequent 10 reputation which was not credited on that day, thus leaving him earning 20 reputation on that day?

Basically, I'm asking whether the subsequent upvotes after reaching the cap from the serial upvoting will be credited?

Comment: This question is oddly specific.

Comment: @Paulie_D I decided to give an example, so it'll be easier to understand :)

Comment: For instance, the 92 votes you recieved on Feb 8th may be viewed by some as suspicious.

Comment: @MartinJames Yup, I know, I don't have a sock puppet, anyways, the votes were all reversed, I was just curious thus came about this question

Comment: @MartinJames Also, a user needs 15 reputation before being able to upvote and 125 reputation to downvote

Comment: @MartinJames Unless *you can confirm that*, it really just hurts people to make accusations out of nowhere. Thousands of users join SO everyday to ask questions, I don't see anything wrong with that. If something is wrong, let the moderators of this site handle it.

Comment: @MartinJames - I should say that I looked into this and I see no correlation at all between the users here. I believe this was simply a case of someone getting an answer, being grateful for it, and mistakenly thinking to reward someone by voting up a series of their other posts. This kind of thing does happen, even though it can look suspicious based only on publicly available information.

Comment: Note that the script does not seem to (always) reverse the **first** vote of the series, only the subsequent ones.

Comment: You could test this out for yourself by serial-upvoting Jon Skeet, and watching his reputation closely.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to the [serial-voting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on the global meta:

> - **Reversals trigger a reputation recalculation.**
>
>   Whenever serial voting gets reversed, all days involved in the serial voting will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened, and any reputation you might have lost due to those serial votes hitting the reputation cap will be given to you at that time. Serial voters will not prevent you from gaining reputation that you deserve.

In particular, the last sentence contains the answer to your question.