# Reputation capped after serial voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, serial-voting

I find that somebody serial voted (2 hours back) and then it got reversed (200 points).

[image]

[image]

Now, the answers that got upvoted after the serial vote reversal is not counted as it is daily capped.  According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316778/what-will-happen-if-a-user-reaches-the-reputation-cap-after-being-serial-voted) post, reputation will be recalculated.  But, the answer that was upvoted after the serial voting is not being considered until now.  Is it a bug?

#### Update

The votes got corrected today

[image]
[image]

Comment: so in the end, serial upvoting someone with a temp account will penalize the user more than serial downvoting the user due to the daily cap?

Comment: Ah you got a great fan

Comment: What if you wait another 24 hours? Come back and update the post tomorrow?

Comment: @Friday It is almost 10 hours after this serial voting reversal happened and I got multiple upvotes.  But, none of them is updated and only those accepted i.e. 15 points gets updated.   My point is that after the serial vote reversal, other votes are not getting counted.

Comment: @Friday What I meant is that those scores are not counted only the ones that get accepted (which doesn't depend on rep cap).  I don't really care about the rep points, but what I meant by posting is to know if there is a bug.

Comment: Just curious: Did the votes end up being corrected eventually?

Comment: @poke No, it didn't.  I waited 2 days and it still didn't

Comment: @poke Looks like I got corrected now.  THanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is just an oddity that happens when serial voting occurs between 00:00 and 03:00 UTC. The system thinks you are currently capped for the day because the count that determines how much you've earned that day is off. It only looks at the total amount you've earned from upvotes that day, and it can't be responsible for looking deeper into that value every time someone casts a vote because that would slow the system down for a somewhat rare case.

The system *will* recalculate your reputation and re-assign 10 reputation from an invalidated vote to a valid vote whenever you get scheduled next (you can always delete and undelete a random post of yours, and then wait ~15 minutes).